# Wrap all div then unwrap outer if inner is wrapped

Tags: jquery

Using the following HTML (on [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/5uworq9t/13/)):

```
<div class='table'>
  <div class='table'></div>

  <div class='table'>
    <div class='table'></div>
    <div class='table'></div>
  </div>

  <div class='table'>
    <div class='table'>
       <div class='table'></div>
    </div>
    <div class='table'>
       <div class='table'></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I want to wrap all `div` with a new `div.wrapper`, but if `div.wrapper` is wrapped with a `div.wrapper` then remove it, filter not to apply it or something:

```
$('div.table').wrap('<div class="wrapper"></div>');
```

New HTML would look like this:

```
<div class='table'>
  <div class='wrapper'>
    <div class='table'></div>
  </div>

  <div class='table'>
    <div class='wrapper'>
      <div class='table'></div>
    </div>
    <div class='wrapper'>
      <div class='table'></div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class='table'>
    <div class='table'>
      <div class='wrapper'>
       <div class='table'></div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class='table'>
      <div class='wrapper'>
       <div class='table'></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: And what did you manage to achieve when you tried to solve this yourself? How far did you get? What went wrong? In what way did it go wrong, what happened instead? Please: read the "*[ask]*" guidelines.

Comment: set up fiddle , tried to unwrap parent but cant get working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are effectively attempting to wrap the innermost div in each "branch" you can wrap the wrapping line in an if statement that checks if the element contains any further candidates for being wrapped.

```js
$('div.table').each(function() {
  if ($(this).find('div.table').length === 0) {
    $(this).wrap('<div class="wrapper"></div>');
  }
});
```

```css
div.wrapper {border:2px solid red;margin:10px}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='table'>do not wrap me
    <div class='table'>inner most table</div>
  <div class='table'>do not wrap me
      <div class='table'>only wrap me</div>
      <div class='table'>only wrap me</div>
  </div>
  <div class='table'>do not wrap me
    <div class='table'>do not wrap me
       <div class='table'>only wrap me</div>
    </div>
    <div class='table'>do not wrap me
       <div class='table'>only wrap me</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```